# Sync-adapter and contentAuthority - how to define?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I am creating my own content provider.
I supposed to choose unique name for `contentAuthority`. But if I define this in a standard way like "com.example.something", then the same value is displayed on the sync screen and there is no way to translate that (resource id can not be passed as value for `contentAuthority`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution - once ContentProvided is defined, its name (label) is displayed.